# Wy should I use namespaces when building a chat wit Socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

I am building a platform where multiple users can interact with each other and get notified when the another user interacts with oneself in a certain way. For example sending a message, sending a request or updating some collaboration objects on the server. Nothing special here.
Therefor I like to use Socket.io on a node server with express (frontend is in angular 7) to keep the user experience as realtime like as possible.

I wonder if I really need to introduce namespaces and rooms, since my current implementation should work well. Could you tell me, if there is a problem with my type of implementation?

I am using some sort of socket connection store as a Map, where all my alive socket connections are. Here is an example of my server-side implementation:

```
// <userId, socket>
var Connections = new Map();

removeConnection = function(socket) {
  console.log("removing User with Id = " + socket.userId);
  Connections.delete(socket.userId);
} 

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  socket.on('register', (userId) => {
    // do some authentication here..
    socket.userId = userId;
    Connections.set(userId, socket);
    console.log("User registered with id " + userId);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    removeConnection(socket);
  });

  socket.on('new_message', (data) => {
    // persist data in DB and so on..

    socket.emit('new_message', data);
    var receiver = Connections.get(data.receiverId);    
    // if receiver is online send message
    if(receiver) {
      receiver.emit('new_message', data);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using any recipient selection (e.g. single recipient or namespaces/rooms) then every message will be delivered to every client. Let's assume that each client sends a "hello" message once he connects. The amount of "hello" messages would grow exponentially with the number of your clients.

Depending on how big you're planning to scale your application that might cause a lot of traffic: n messages would cause n² transactions... 1000 users sending 1 message each would already be 1.000.000 transactions..

To make the communication more efficient you might perform any of these steps:

- direct messages to a single user shoud be send only to that user, not broadcastet on the whole platform. you can do that with the connection.emit("the message") command. io.emit("the message") would send to every connected client
- messages concerning a specific topic that not all of your useres are interested in could be realized using "rooms". any user can subscribe to an arbitary number of rooms to recieve those notficactions. all others won't be spammed by the messages.
  (https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)

Another issue might be privacy... If user A is sending a message to user B then you don't want users C,D,E.. to receive that broadcast as well. Even if your client filters out messages which are not meant for the user, the information would still be sent to all of them in plain text which I would consider an unnecessary privacy breach.

Here's a great cheat sheet about recipient selection and different methods of sending a message: 
https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Your code recieves messages from any connected client and forwards it only to the respective recipient (if found in the map). That's just fine for direct messaging between users. If you want to broadcast updated infos on some collaborative project you should rather use rooms and namespaces as described above.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I wonder if what you're saying goes for me too.
In my case each client has it's own socket connection, with an own url like: ws://localhost:9500/socket.io-client/?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1. So there is no broadcasting when I emit an event in a specific socket connection. (well I hope)
Other connections don't receive the messages, only the one sending and the addressee. 
Am I right?

Comment: With socket.io the server has a seperate "connection" with each client - that's standard procedure. Socket.io offers many different ways of selecting subsets of those connected clients as recipents. There's a great overview of all these methods here: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

It seems that your code is fine.. Your command "receiver.emit()" sends only to the client on that connection. "socket.emit()" would send to all clients.